# Hashtag linking in AngularJS and JS

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm new to regex expressions and don't really understand them. I'm getting comments from a PHP script that may or may not include hashtags. I need to create a link out of the hashtag (not including urls or if the hashtag has a commas or a space in it)

So far I've looked online and found this:

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<a href=\"hashtag.php?tag=$2\">$2</a>");
```

However, the link generated is:

```
<a href="hashtag.php?tag=#thenameofhashtag">#thenameofhashtag</a>
```

I need to be able to exclude the hashtag from the tag= variable line. How can I modify the expression to achieve this and are there any angularJS way's of doing this? Additionally, are languages (Chinese, Japanese, etc) or characters that are not in UTF-8 encoded create problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the `#` from the capturing group so that it is not captured in `$2` as

```
(^|\s)#([a-z\d-]+)/ig
```

- `#([a-z\d-]+)` Here the `#` is moved outside so that only `[a-z\d-]+` is captured

**Example**

```
string.replace(/(^|\s)#([a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<a href=\"hashtag.php?tag=$2\">#$2</a>");
// => <a href="hashtag.php?tag=thenameofhashtag">#thenameofhashtag</a>
```